# Passing Python string literal as argument, surrounded with and without square brackets

Tags: python

I have the following code segment (from a working Google sample [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/label-tutorial)):

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().create_scoped(
      ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
```

I removed the square brackets around the string literal and tried it as follows:

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().create_scoped(
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform')
```

No difference, the application still works the same.  My questions: What are the square brackets for, and even though they seem to be redundant above, are they supposed to be an insurance against something else?

I am running Python 3.5.1 on Windows 7 x86.

Comment: "What are square brackets for"? Perhaps you should check out the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: you can pass multiple args  in the list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets are called a [list display](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) and produce a `list` object. Apparently the API accepts either a list or a string. That the *specific* API accepts both a string and a list does not mean that the syntax is otherwise meaningless.

The [`create_scopes()` documentation](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/source/oauth2client.client.html#oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials.create_scoped) is a bit vague on the subject, just documenting the argument as `scopes` (plural) and stating that it will *Create a Credentials object for the given scopes.*. The `GoogleCredentials` class acts as a dispatcher for various environments (where credentials are read from a file or from a App Engine storage), but from what I can see the `scopes` value is eventually passed to [`oauth2client.util.scopes_to_string()`](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/9f9661a8c3909a9f75df729a03b0c5f8c5748bae/oauth2client/util.py#L145-L161), which uses `' '.join()` if the argument is not a string already; so for multiple scopes you can pass in a tuple, list, generator containing scope strings, or as one space-separated string.

Comment: *"That the specific API accepts both a string and a list does not mean that the syntax is otherwise meaningless."* Excellent, thank you.